# Little-$o$ notation in CLT proof using Levy Continuity Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, central-limit-theorem

I am stuck at understanding the little-$o$ notation used in the proof of CLT using Levy's theorem. Specifically, I want to understand why for fixed $n$,
$$
1 - \frac{t^2}{2n} + o\left( \frac{t^2}{n} \right) = \exp\left( -\frac{t^2}{2n} + o\left( \frac{t^2}{n} \right) \right).
$$

---

Being new to the little $o$ notation, I understand the above equality is saying for any $f$ such that $\frac{n}{t^2}f(t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$, there exists $g$ such that $\frac{n}{t^2}g(t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$ and
$$
1 - \frac{t^2}{2n} + f(t) = \exp\left( -\frac{t^2}{2n} + g(t) \right).
$$
Knowing $\exp(x) = 1 + x + o(x) = 1 + x + h(x)$ for some $h \sim o(x)$, I see
$$
1 - \frac{t^2}{2n} + f(t) = \exp\left( -\frac{t^2}{2n} + f(t) \right) - h\left( -\frac{t^2}{2n}+f(t)) \right) \stackrel{?}{=}\exp\left( -\frac{t^2}{2n} + o\left( \frac{t^2}{n} \right) \right).
$$
My question is why is the last equality true? i.e. What is the function $g$ here?

Comment: Using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series how to write $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\cdots$ with little-$o$?

Comment: @zkutch I might be misunderstanding something, but is it not $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2)$?

Comment: $$\exp s=1+s+O(s^2)$$ 
For $s=-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o\left(\frac{t^2}{n}\right)$
$$\exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o\left(\frac{t^2}{n}\right)\right)=1-\frac{t^2}{2n}+o\left(\frac{t^2}{n}\right)+O\left(\frac{t^4}{n^2}\right)$$
as $t\to0$. Note that $o\left(\frac{t^2}{n}\right)+O\left(\frac{t^4}{n^2}\right)=o\left(\frac{t^2}{n}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $f(t) = o(g(t))$ for $t → 0$ if for every $ε > 0$ there is some $ δ > 0$ such that for every $ |t| < δ $, it holds that $ |f(t)| \leq ε |g(t)|$. Equivalently, there is some function $φ(t)$ defined in a neighbourhood of 0 such that $f(t) = φ(t)g(t)$ and $φ(t) → 0 $ as $t → 0$.

---

To show that $1 - \frac{t^2}{2n} + o\left( \frac{t^2}{n} \right) = \exp\left( -\frac{t^2}{2n} + o\left( \frac{t^2}{n} \right) \right),$ we observe that  $\exp(x) = 1+x+o(x) = 1+x + x φ(x)$ for some function $φ$ as above. Thus we have $$ \exp(x + o(x)) = 1 + x + o(x) + (x + o(x))φ(x + o(x)),
$$
and it remains to check that $(x + o(x))φ(x + o(x)) = o(x)$ for $x → 0$. Indeed, $|x + o(x)| \leq 2|x|$ for $x$ in some neighbourhood of 0, hence $φ(x + o(x)) → 0 $ as $x → 0$, implying that for any $ε > 0$, $|(x + o(x))φ(x + o(x))| \leq ε|x|$ for all $x$ in some neighbourhood of 0.